# How to set up Umbraco and React JS

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, umbraco8

I'm trying to build a website using Umbraco 8 CMS, but I want to write the front end code in React JS.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbraco Heartcore would be the way to go.  But I believe it's only available with the Cloud version.

https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-heartcore/

If you're not using the cloud version, you could try using Umbraco API Controllers to expose your data as JSON.

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/

Then from your React application you can call the endpoints.